# How to insert the parentheses and values if missing string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here i have group of string with comma, like "stack,flow(2),over(4),temp(0)" if just string without open and close parentheses value, i need to insert the with (1). stack(1).

```
Expected scenario :

1.insert (1) missing open & close parentheses 
2.within parentheses should be >0 numeric values.
3.within parentheses if any alpha character , show error message.
```

As i need to validate that with in parentheses value should be numberic. I have tried the some scenrio, but i need help to insert (1).

```
function testCases(str){
    return (
    str.match(new RegExp("\\([^,]+\\)","g")).length  == str.split(",").length
    );
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8t26/2/)

Comment: What is the rule about numeric value inside parenthesis ? I don't understand why it's 2, then 4, then 0 .. ?

Comment: just any number inside the parenthesis and should be >0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correctly understand you want to insert `(1)` before the comma if there's no parenthesized group, then you can do this :

```
var str = "stack,flow(2),over(4),temp(0)";
str = str.replace(/([^)]),/g, "$1(1),");
```

Result : `"stack(1),flow(2),over(4),temp(0)"`

If you also want to ensure the group contains a strictly positive integer, you may do

```
var str = "stack,flow(2),flow(k),over(4),neg(-3),temp(0)";
str = str.split(',').map(function(s){
    return s.replace(/(\((.*?)\))?$/, function(s,d,e) {
        return '('+ (e>0?e:1)+')'
    })
}).join(',');
```

Result : `"stack(1),flow(2),flow(1),over(4),neg(1),temp(1)"`

Comment: Its just example i have given stack but any string can come with out parenthesis like stack,flow(2),over,temp and as well many number of string with comma not only four.

Comment: Not a problem, this will work for an unlimited number of strings. But validation part (parenthesis have to contain integer) is missing here.

Comment: But last place not inserting the (1) ie, for temp.

Comment: 1. it should not accept stacka(z),over(0) error message. 
2. if any parenthesis then inserting (1).
3. But last place not inserting the (1) ie, for temp

Comment: @user2848031 I'm still unsure of the exact requirement but can you check the new version ? If it's not what you want, can you update your question with a list of strings and the related desired results ?

Comment: @dystroy Thank you soo much for your update. I looking one scenrio is stack(1),flow(k)(1),over(1),temp(1) if other than numeric that give me error message or remove . flow(k)

Comment: @user2848031 Updated to handle flow(k) => flow(1)

Answer (score 0):

well, my solution is a little complicated, but more relatable, e.g. it works for:

```
stacka(z),flow(2),over(4),temp(0),ccc
```

Here the code:

```
function convert(str) {

    //ends with (num)
    var regexObj = /\(\d+\)$/;

    return str.split(',').map(function(p) {

        return p + (regexObj.test(p) ? '' : '(1)');

    }).join(',');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/pU2Q7/

Comment: it should not accept stacka(z),over(0) error message.and if any parenthesis then inserting (1).